# Report export options / updating existing filter criteria after adding new picklist value

Tags: apex, reporting, reports-api

We added a new picklist value to an existing picklist field and now the challenge is to identify all reports where the picklist is used and update the filter criteria. Currently we are looking through each report which is tedious and waste of time to do.

1) Is there a way to mass export all reports with filter criteria? I can then open all the reports in excel and do a search on all open files.

**Alternate approach:**

Using report API I was able to get the list of all reports by querying folders first and associating the ownerid with the folder id and the org id( since unfiled reports are owned by organization).

2) The biggest hurdle is identifying "Obsolete"reports,is there a filter that shows if the report is obsolete( I understand that the metadata could have changed/ export report options could have been turned off etc..)

The reason why I need to identify obsolete reports is because when I query all reports by folder even if one report is obsolete the whole code fails in developer console.

**code:**

I care only about the report Ids where the filter value contains "Hardware" so not doing any fancy approach. All I have to do is to identify report Ids where filter value contains hardware and update the report filters.

```
    // Get the report ID
List<folder> folderlist = [SELECT AccessType,Type,name FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Report'];
system.debug('%%%%'+folderlist);

List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName,ownerid FROM Report where ownerid =: folderlist OR ownerid=: userinfo.getOrganizationId() ];
system.debug('#######'+reportList);
map<string,string> allfilter = new map<string,string>();
List<string> allfils = new list<string>();

// Get the report metadata
for(report r : reportlist){
    Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(r.id);
    Reports.ReportMetadata reportMd = describe.getReportMetadata();

    // Get all filters for every report where value contains hardware.
    for(integer i=0;i<reportMd.getReportFilters().size();i++){
            if(reportMd.getReportFilters()[i].getValue().contains('Hardware')){
                allfilter.put('Report ID: '+r.id+string.valueOf(i),'Filter column: '+reportMd.getReportFilters()[i].getColumn()+' Filter Value: '+ reportMd.getReportFilters()[i].getValue());
            }
    }
}

system.debug('Report map values'+ allfilter);
```

Comment: You can use force.com IDE for eclipse. or any other and pull all reports and edit/search in metadata

Comment: Hmm sounds an easy option, ill give it a try